# Advertising in Windows 10 universal apps

Tags: c#, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

iv been updating my windows 8.1 apps to universal windows 10 and I'm having issues with the admediator which iv set up to use Microsoft ads and ad duplex and for some reason it will only show ads for a few seconds then loses them, has anyone else seen this issue as I'm currently going through it with ad duplex and they don't understand why its happening either, also does anyone know of a better advertising platform to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're already getting support from AdDuplex stick with them. What version of the AdDuplex control do you have? Make sure it's 10.0.0.3 (or higher) - You may need to update it via the NuGet if it was installed as part of configuring AdMediator.
Also, check what size you're setting the ad control to be.

"Better" is highly subjective when it comes to different ad providers. Each will provide different results for different types of ads in different types of apps and in different markets. This will also change over time based on what different advertisers are trying to achieve. Additionally, AdDuplex is providing a different service to traditional advertisers.
It's because of all these factors that mediation is so important.

Comment: I'm using the current version I think its more to do with Microsofts admediator than adduplex as if the ad is clicked on it starts to work correctly so I was more looking for something to use instead of admediator

Comment: @XCDev the only real alternative to AdMediator was AdRotator but that doesn't have Win10 support. You could look at porting it though https://github.com/Adrotator/AdrotatorV2